# Github wrong commmit diff

Tags: github

I just forked a repository into

https://github.com/SoftwareAndOutsourcing/securimage

edited a file and pushed some changes:

https://github.com/SoftwareAndOutsourcing/securimage/commit/3f4599e636c532143f198bb9ef2e397a9185af9c

However the github diff does not show these properly, but if I download the files and compare them using a desktop diff tool, they show fine. I also usually work with svn and I never had a similar issue. Why this is happening?

PS. I deleted and created forked again the repository, added a .gitattributes file https://github.com/SoftwareAndOutsourcing/securimage/blob/master/.gitattributes and then tried to upload the file. I has the same issues. With a text editor, I can see the line ends and spaces are fine on my computer.

Here is the file I'm trying to commit just like it's on my computer:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/ngv7dc80ji3i65s/securimage.zip

Comment: What do you mean by 'not show properly'?

Comment: If you check the commit link above, you will see that there are not any changes really in the diff, just compare any old and new block. And the changes I committed are not showing there (you can see this downloading the committed file and the previous version and using a diff tool).

Comment: See my answer; there's different whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually checking the files shows that you've committed different whitespace to what the original file has, as you've modified and changed the line endings on the lines that *look* like nothing has changed visually.

See this screenshot:
[image: manual diff in vim]

On the left, it's the 'old' file. On the right, it's your new one. Note that on lines 856, 857, 858, there's the `^M` at the end in pink in one but not the other? That's why Git noticed the whitespace change and adding those lines to your diff.

Comment: These does not show in my system, but I think it's the git client which is changing these: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: I added https://github.com/SoftwareAndOutsourcing/securimage/blob/master/.gitattributes but I still get the same results.

Comment: You were right, but the files which was not normalized was the original one, what confused me.